# MSI GE70 2PE Apache pro - memory upgrade

Tags: laptop, memory, laptop-repair, ddr3, sodimm

I need to upgrade the laptop to 32GB, 16GB 1 piece.  It has only 2 slots.

at present the memory specification is below:
https://www.memorycow.co.uk/8gb-8gb-x1-ddr3l-ram-memory-non-ecc-sodimm-1600mhz-pc3l-12800

i wannna purchase crucial 32gb, and the specification is below
http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/ct2kit204864bf160b#productDetails

As a laymen, i think their pins are identical. both 204 pins, DDR3L, CL11 and non-ecc ram (both are not for server).

am i missing something ? can upgrade ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't put SO-DIMM 32GB in your laptop cause it only allows 16GB Maximum as the [MSI specifications](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GE70-2PE-Apache-Pro/Specification) is telling us: `DDR3L up to 16GB x 2 DIMMs`

---

[Here](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/MSI-(Micro-Star)/ge70-2pe-apache-pro)
 is the RAM you can easily put on your computer, I can let you choose from there.

Comment: hmm... i used to have HP Pavilion DV7 which official saying only 8GB (4GB x2)...

https://support.hp.com/my-en/document/c01509830

But i used 16GB ... 8GB x2 pieces and it was working okay. Use it for more than 4 years. Bought used in 2013

I assumed during 1st Generation i7 was introduced (around 2010 ?), 8GB DDR3 1 piece SODIMM was not available yet.

This MSI was replacing my old DV7. DV7 was using DDR3 and MSI should use DDR3L... (low voltage)... but to my surprise it still works so i keep my old 16GB DDR3 to use in this MSI laptop...

maybe in 2014 there is 16GB DDR3 ?

Comment: Depending on the motherboard, try at your own risk. We can't tell if we haven't tested (what MSI/HP should do and inform us) that's why.

Comment: oh so it's not something fix... okay i will update later when i purchased the RAM... thanks